# Html dynamic table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a small system (for personal use) in order to analyze some school marks.
In an Html page (**index.html**), I would like to insert a JavaScript script that calculates the averages of the values of **mydata.js** of the same subject and put them into a table in the **index.html** page.

**mydata.js** looks like this:

```
myData([
{"subject": 1, "value": 5},
{"subject": 2, "value": 4},
{"subject": 3, "value": 7},
{"subject": 1, "value": 5},
{"subject": 2, "value": 7},
{"subject": 3, "value": 6},
{"subject": 2, "value": 3}
]);
```

**index.html** looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>SUBJECT: 1</td>
                <td>AVERAGE: x</td>  <!-- Instead of x should be 5 -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SUBJECT: 2</td>
                <td>AVERAGE: y</td>  <!-- Instead of y should be 4.6 -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SUBJECT: 3</td>
                <td>AVERAGE: z</td>  <!-- Instead of z should be 6.5 -->
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="path/mydata.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck here. I tried and tried but I can't go on.

Comment: what is myData?

Comment: It's the object that contains my values.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/czxbyahd/)

Below given is the relevant part of the JS that I've  used

```
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  if (myData[i].subject == '1') {
    avg1 = avg1 + myData[i].value;
    count1++;
  } else if (myData[i].subject == '2') {
    avg2 = avg2 + myData[i].value;
    count2++;
  } else if (myData[i].subject == '3') {
    avg3 = avg3 + myData[i].value;
    count3++;
  }
}

document.getElementById('avg_sub1').innerHTML = avg1 / count1;
document.getElementById('avg_sub2').innerHTML = avg2 / count2;
document.getElementById('avg_sub3').innerHTML = avg3 / count3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple pseudo solution.

```
<script>
var data = [
{ "subject": 1, "value": 5 },
{ "subject": 2, "value": 4 },
{ "subject": 3, "value": 7 },
{ "subject": 1, "value": 5 },
{ "subject": 2, "value": 7 },
{ "subject": 3, "value": 6 },
{ "subject": 2, "value": 3 }
];
var averageArray = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {        
    var average = data[i].value; 
    for (var j = 0 ; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data[i].subject == data[j].subject) {
            average = (average + data[j].value) / 2; 
        }
    }

    averageArray.push(average);
}
</script>
```

Now your `averageArray` will have data like `[5,4.6,6.5.....]`

Use this to display on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some library to do this.

E.g [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)

Look [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcm836qu/)

```
var myData =[
{"subject": "mmm", "value": 5},
{"subject": "bbb", "value": 4},
{"subject": "ccc", "value": 7},
{"subject": "mmm", "value": 5},
{"subject": "bbb", "value": 7},
{"subject": "ccc", "value": 6},
{"subject": "bbb", "value": 3}
];

var tr = '';
var subjects = _.groupBy(myData, "subject");
for (var sub in subjects) {
  var s = _.pluck(subjects[sub], 'value');
  var avg = _.reduce(s, function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0) / (s.length === 0 ? 1 : s.length);
  tr += '<tr><td>'+sub+'</td><td>'+avg+'</td></tr>';
}
document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = tr;
```